# How to use dynamic to eliminateduplicate code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I  have tried to use the example form [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidebb/using-c-dynamic-to-call-static-members) to eliminate the code duplication.

```
 if (Categories != null) {
        foreach (var item in Categories)
        {
            if (item.ID != 0)
            {
                Category category = Category.Load(item.ID);
                category.Name = item.Name;
                category.Project = project;
                category.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                {
                    Category category = new Category(project, item.Name);
                    category.Save();
                }
            }
        }
}
        
           
            if (Priorities != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Priorities)
                {
                    if (item.ID != 0)
                    {
                        Priority priority = Priority.Load(item.ID);
                        priority.Name = item.Name;
                        priority.Project = project;
                        priority.Save();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                        {
                            Priority priority = new Priority(project, item.Name);
                            priority.Save();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

---

I am trying to do something as follows, but having the error message

> Cannot invoke a non-delegate type
> in the part

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name)) 
                { 
                    dynamic newObject = typeDynamic(project, item.Name); 
                    newObject.Save(); 
                }
```

---

```
SaveObjects(typeof(Category), Categories.ToList(), project);
 SaveObjects(typeof(Priority), Priorities.ToList(), project);
```

---

Any help Please.

Thanks.

What is wrong and how can I correct that?

```
 private void SaveObjects(Type type, dynamic currentItems, Project project)
    {
        dynamic typeDynamic = new StaticMembersDynamicWrapper(type);
        foreach (var item in currentItems)
        {
            if (item.ID != 0)
            {
                dynamic classValues = typeDynamic.Load(item.ID);
                classValues.Name = item.Name;
                classValues.Project = project;
                classValues.Save();

            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                {
                    dynamic newObject = typeDynamic(project, item.Name);
                    newObject.Save();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined typeDynamic to be a dynamic type but later try to use it as an actual Type (using it as a constructor `typeDynamic(...)`).  That's not how they are intended to be used, just access to members using the dot (`typeDynamic.someMember`).  Reading through the use of the `StaticMembersDynamicWrapper`, it doesn't give you access to the constructors, only static members.  You'd need to implement `TryInvoke` in the StaticMembersDynamicWrapper class to use the type as a constructor.  Add this to the class:

```
public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    ConstructorInfo ctor = _type.GetConstructor(args.Select(arg => arg.GetType()).ToArray());
    if (ctor == null)
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    result = ctor.Invoke(args);
    return true;
}
```

Not terribly robust but should work enough for you.  I would strongly recommend however a simpler approach as suggested by ck or my other non-dynamic approach.

---

A different (non-dynamic) approach you could take is to use delegates to your static functions.  Refer to my answer in this question, [Curious problem involving generics and static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376792/curious-problem-involving-generics-and-static-methods).

Comment: It`s failing on code the code
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name)) 
                { 
                    dynamic newObject = typeDynamic(project, item.Name); 
                    newObject.Save(); 
                }

Answer (score 2):

This would probably be much easier by declaring an interface that exposes all of the shared properties and methods required, then just implement the interface for each class, and write the shared code to work on the interface.